# How to handle multiple mongo ChangeStreams in a multi instance service

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, changestream

I am trying to solve a problem where I am listening on a **Mongo Changestream** but in a production environment, we have multiple instances of the service running so in each instance I get the 'on change' event which I need to process.
But I want to process the change **ONLY ONCE** but here it is being processed multiple times(Number of instances of the service)

I need a way to ensure that each change Event is processed only once.
Thought of using Redis but then there is a chance of collision when two instances try to add the same **on change** event at the same time.
Please refer the diagram below for a rough idea of my architecture.
[image: Overview of my architecture]

Comment: Hi @Avelanche , did you manage to handle this situation? I'm facing the same problem and I'm looking for some ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I did. I used Redis and stored the Mango change stream id in it. And for each change stream I checked if the key exists in the Cache. Thus I was able to implement it.